# Execute same test with different configurations

Tags: .net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I've got [a project](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/tree/feature/InMemoryTesting) supporting multiple database providers (SQL, Sqlite, InMemory). For the [API tests](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/tree/feature/InMemoryTesting/Backend/Tests/Sppd.TeamTuner.Tests.Integration.Api) I'm using the InMemory DB for performance reasons. For the [integration tests](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/tree/feature/InMemoryTesting/Backend/Tests/Sppd.TeamTuner.Tests.Integration) I would like to run all tests for all providers to test migrations, DB constraints etc.

Is there a way to configure the integration tests to run with the different configurations?

[edit] Build something like this?
https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/542
https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/TestRunner/Program.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I've discovered `[Theory]` the solution was trivial. A test execution now specifies the provider to use. I've predefined the configuration file to use for each provider; this is being copied to the config file which will be used and the test executes.

```
    [SkippableTheory]
    [InlineData("MsSql")]
    [InlineData("Sqlite")]
    [InlineData("InMemory")]
    public async Task DoesNotLoadUnspecifiedNavigationPropertiesTest(string provider)
    {
        Skip.If(provider == "MsSql" && !SkipHelper.IsWindowsOS(), "Ignore when not executing on Windows");

        async Task Test()
        {
            // Perform the test with assertions
        }

        await ExecuteTestForProvider(provider, Test);
    }

    private async Task ExecuteTestForProvider(string provider, Func<Task> test)
    {
        try
        {
            SetConfiguration(provider);
            Initialize();

            await test.Invoke();
        }
        finally
        {
            Teardown();
        }
    }
```

The full implementation ca be found [here](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/blob/23a806d3494dd11ba2369bce01f048fbd60e5dda/Backend/Tests/Sppd.TeamTuner.Tests.Integration.Repository/RepositoryTests.cs)